# How could I set the default contact store?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts

I have an LG L5 (E610), running Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich MR1).

Recently, I moved all my contacts that were stored as Phone or SIM contacts to Google contacts in order to get them synced.

Now, I have only Google contacts.

But, when I create a new contact, the default store seems to be the Phone store, and I find no option where I can set Google as the default store.

Googling around a bit brought up one solution that *sounded* reasonable: display only the Google contacts, in the address book, then Google will be the default for a new contact. But, even this doesn't work; if I only display Google contacts, my phone still selects the Phone storage as default and I **cannot see my newly created contact.**

Any suggestions as to how I can set the default contact store? Or is this impossible?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Try to go to Settings>Apps>All Apps>Contacts (not contact storage) and clear data.
Also try to combine all the suggestions:

1. cleared data in contacts app as written above
2. selected the display only contacts from whatever you want
3. made a dummy contact, selecting the desired store location
4. reboot

I basically tried all the solutions, so it's a little hard to give the exact way to go about this. Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't even need a reboot. Just tried out on my restored phone. Simply cleared contact data. Changed the settings to display only phones from... Tried adding phone number and the default location is as selected. Needed to do only 1,2 from the list